# Windows 7 stalls on 'Please wait...'

Tags: windows-7, boot

Running a Win 7 x64 machine.  About a week and a half ago it started stalling on the 'Please wait...' before login.  I tried the hotfix https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2617858 to no avail.  I am able to get past it once the screensaver kicks on and I wake it.  Thoughts anyone?

Comment: capture a boot trace of the issue: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE (the Win8.1 WPT also works fro WIn7) and share it

Comment: have you captured the boot trace?

Comment: I downloaded and installed the WPT.  Executed the script.  The trace appears to be running indefinitely and does so on each startup.  Is this normal behavior?

Comment: after a boot you should see a timer which tick down from 120 seconds to 1.

Comment: That happened on the first run but I dont see that anymore but it appears to be running the trace on each startup. How can I  unschedule or disable the trace?

Comment: Nvm found this to remove the trace http://superuser.com/questions/602843/huge-etl-file-that-wont-go-away-in-system32-possible-remnant-of-xbootmgr

Comment: run the first command again and give me the generated file, so that I can take a look at it

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxJjaCFuo-5LUDFyOGJKZVE3Y2M/view?usp=sharing

Let me know when you grab it so I can pull the link down

Comment: ok, I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before the screensaver (`c:\windows\system32\morley.scr`) kicks up, Windows Installers installs some software which is triggered by `Kaspersky NetworkAgent` (`klnagent.exe`). Look in Kaspersky logs to see what it does during boot.

This causes a lot of disk IO during boot and slows down boot a lot.

[image]

I checked the callstack of some disk activity and see that a Lenovo driver called `DzHDD64.sys` is involved. Look if this driver is really required and if not, remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Tested and verified in a domain environment.  "Please wait" is not necessarily a computer problem especially in a enterprise environment.  Rebooting DC helped resolve the problem which was likely caused by DNS caching.  Hopefully will save someone time versus troubleshooting the computer in vain.

Comment: I can't see any mention of a domain environment in the question ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I can't see any mention that it is *not* in a domain environment either. Ryan B's post helped me.

Answer (score 2):

The "please wait" slows down once I add the computer to an OU with scripts.  Long story short I went ahead and ran the https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3172605 and only had 2 spins of please wait. Special thanks to Andre to lead me towards the right direction. I've been researching this issue for 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

For testing purpose please try to disable the following services: ***Windows Error Reporting, Network Location Service, Network List service***

1. Power off the PC
2. Power on and press **repeadiatly F8** you see the **Safe Mode screen**
3. Select **Safe Mode with Networking**
4. Login to your PC
5. Press **Win+R** and enter **services.msc** into the window followed by **pressing return**
6. Locate above services (*Windows Error Reporting, Network Location Service, Network List service*)
7. **Double-click them** (one by one) and change the **startup type** to **Disabled**
8. **Restart** your computer **gracefully**! (Start -> Shutdown)

Those services aren't really necessary but might block your PC from booting.

If this doesn't help, please provide more info, like is your PC part of a domain?

Comment: Will do @Andre stay tuned

Comment: I tried these and it didn't work.  I didn't go into Safe Mode though, does that matter?  Yes I am part of a domain.  Its my work laptop. I suppose I could go through our tech support guys but I am a systems/programming guy and like fixing it myself

Comment: I guess your boot time is normal, when you are connected with a cable at work within your domain? An delayed boot time is normal outside of your domain. To confirm that theory I would suggest you to leave the domain for testing purpose and join a workgroup. If your boot time is normal we can think of a solution.

Comment: What you could also check is, if the group policy for waiting until your mapped network drives are connected is set. This would delay your boot extremely. I have to check where the policy is located when I'm at home

Comment: To check my last point: Win+R -> gpedit.msc -> Computer Config\Administrative Templates\System\Logon -> `Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon` set this to disbled

Comment: And last but not least, you could try this hotfix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2617858

Comment: Did the hotfix before my OP.  Check the gpedit settings and its set to not configured

Answer (score 1):

Run Disk Cleanup and make sure Windows Updates Temporary files are checked, and restart.

There may be a broken Update somewhere.

Comment: Tried this already to no avail